# How to make NSNumberFormatter stringFromNumber only take positive number?

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I am using `NSNumberFormatter`'s `stringFromNumber` to get string from a float number. I've set this and only want to take positive number.

```
numberFormatter.positiveFormat = @"#######0.00";
numberFormatter.negativeFormat = nil; // or @""
```

What I want is when there is a negative number, the string should be nil or empty. But the code seems don't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Before passing the number to stringFromNumber, do a absolute function on the number.

```
abs(number); // if your number is int
fabs(number); // if your number is float
```

**EDITED**:
In that case, a simple if statement will do

```
NSString *result = @"";
if (number<0) {
   // do nothing

} else {
  result = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];

}
```

Comment: Thanks @GeneCode. But that's not what I want. If I do a `fabs`, then I would get string when there is a negative number, which I want nil or empty string.

Comment: Yes this would work. Still wonder how to work it out with `NSNumberFormatter`? Why can't I set a nil/empty format for the specify number?

Comment: Because a nil format means the default (ie not formatted), hence it will return your number as it is.